# Generate .war file from web app

Tags: war, webstorm

How can I generate .war file from web app containing just HTML, CSS & JavaScript?
Is there any way to do that using webstorm?

Comment: Duplicate of [Generate .war file from web app containing just HTML, CSS & JavaScript](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20080538/generate-war-file-from-web-app-containing-just-html-css-javascript/)

Answer (score 3):

I think IntelliJ has a way of doing it but Webstorm doesn't.
http://www.jetbrains.com/idea/webhelp/configuring-web-application-deployment.html

However if you have Java SDK installed and environment variables set for it you can create .war files from the command line. Just navigate to your project area and use the command

```
jar -cvf myApplication.war myApplicationFolderName
```

Hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can configure a grunt file and make a war task 
https://www.npmjs.com/package/grunt-war
the good thing about this is that you will be independent from the IDE or editor you're using. 
In practical terms, it worked for me